# Convert JSON String to JSON Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

I understand there are many similar questions exist, however I couldn't find a proper answer.

Consider the Javascript object,

```
var a = [ { defaultCount:'200' , timeintervals : [{ day:'Weekday', from:'9:00', to:'18:00', count:'100' }, { day:'Weekday', from:'9:00', to:'18:00', count:'100' } ]}];
```

Now running **a[0].defaultCount** gives me "200" as expected.

Now the same Javascript object, I am putting inside double quotes.

```
var b = "[ { defaultCount:'200' , timeintervals : [{ day:'Weekday', from:'9:00', to:'18:00', count:'100' }, { day:'Weekday', from:'9:00', to:'18:00', count:'100' } ]}]";
```

here b[0] gives me "[" and b[4] gives me "d" so on.

If I understand correctly, var a is JavaScript Object and var b is String.
I am receiving var b from the Java side as a String.
How do I convert var b into a form that I can iterate as I do on var a ?

I have tried :
**var c =  JSON.parse(b)** but getting syntax error.

I really do not wish to change the JSON format much as it is the template used in the Java end as well.
Are there any easy workarounds ?

[console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNik5.png)

Comment: JSON is a standard/specification that requires properties and strings in double quotes

Comment: i would recommenst to fix the source.

Comment: Why are you just adding double quotes around JSON? What's the goal here? You can always use `JSON.stringify` to convert your object to a proper JSON string representation.

Comment: What if you remove the double quotes ?

Comment: `eval()` would do what you like. As long as you can live with the ups and downs.

Comment: @JavaScript MDN Docs strongly suggest to **never use** `eval()`

Comment: @Neil: I am aware of it. Still it would work here.

Comment: @ Andrea Giammarchi   @Nina Scholz  It would be the ideal solution to fix the Java side. However it would upset the existing logic written in Java side to parse it. Also there are I am passing special chars such as ":"  which need to be escaped properly.

Comment: "Quoteless JSON" is usually a valid subset of YAML; for the safest option I'd look into a Javascript YAML parser… Alas in this particular case, it's apparently missing the space after the `:` and so turns into garbage too… http://nodeca.github.io/js-yaml/

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin , Neil  I have added the quotes here just to show you the behavior. In actual case I am passing the JSON as a String from Java side and storing it in a field in Velocity template. Then using JavaScript I try to read  the field value (for further processing ) which obviously gives me a String..

Comment: @JavaScript  eval() works perfectly in this case !!  I am going with it. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score -1):

```
[{ 
  "defaultCount":"200" , 
  "timeintervals": [{ "day":"Weekday", "from":"9:00", "to":"18:00", "count":"100" }, { "day":"Weekday", "from":"9:00","to":"18:00", "count":"100"}]
}]
```

use double quotes

Comment: I am afraid the same won't work when it is passed as String which is the root problem I am trying to solve.

"[{
  "defaultCount":"200" , 
  "timeintervals": [{ "day":"Weekday", "from":"9:00", "to":"18:00", "count":"100" }, { "day":"Weekday", "from":"9:00","to":"18:00", "count":"100"}]
}]"

gives syntax error.